# XMLParser not calling delegate methods

Tags: xml, swift, swift3

For a time I've been using [SWXMLHash](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash) for parsing XML in my projects but now it doesn't support Swift 3.0 at the moment so I've decided to start working on my own XML parsing class to do so.

I have done the basics but the delegate methods of XMLParse needed for parsing are not called therefore the parse does not start. I am trying to parse this [file](http://www.bilbao.net/WebServicesBilbao/WSBilbao?s=ODPRESBICI&u=OPENDATA&p0=A&p1=A) and really I don't know what am I missing. To test it out I'm working on a Playground and this is what I have so far:

```
import Foundation

class MyXMLParser: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {

//var myParser: XMLParser
var myParser: XMLParser!
var urlToParse: URL


init(urlToParse: String) {

    self.urlToParse = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlToParse)
    myParser = XMLParser(contentsOf: self.urlToParse)!

    super.init()
}

func parseXMLFeed() {

    print("STARTING XML FILE PARSING")
    myParser.delegate = self
    myParser.parse()
    print("ENDED XML FILE PARSING")
}

func parserDidStartDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {

    print("DOCUMENT STARTED")
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {

    print("DID START ELEMENT")

    if (elementName == "NOMBRE") {
        print("    didStartElement")
    }
}
}

var myParser = MyXMLParser(urlToParse: "http://www.bilbao.net/WebServicesBilbao/WSBilbao?s=ODPRESBICI&u=OPENDATA&p0=A&p1=A")
myParser.parseXMLFeed()
```

The console only shows this

```
STARTING XML FILE PARSING
ENDED XML FILE PARSING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"http://www.bilbao.net/...."` is not a *file URL*. With your code

```
self.urlToParse = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlToParse)
```

the parser tries to open a file with that name on your local computer,
which of course fails. You can also verify the the return value of
`myParser.parse()` is `false`, indicating that parsing the document failed.

You can use `URL(string: urlToParse)` instead to create a URL 
referring to the remote resource.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I've missed it. Thanks!